# How to set equal scale for axes in pyqtgraph plot?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

In docs of AxisItem I found phrase "By default, the axis scaling is 1.0". But when  executing simplest program with line

```
plotWidget = pg.plot()
```

scales for x and y are different. How to adjust them?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
y = range(0, 100)
x = range(0, 100)
plt = pg.plot(x, y, pen='r')
plt.setFixedSize(1000, 1000)
plt.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

Comment: This just works in this specific case where you've manually specified corresponding plot size and data ranges. There's no mechanism for updating the plot size based on a possibly different data range.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/1143), now `setAspectLocked` works.

This circle will remain a circle, even after zoom/pan.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
x =  2+np.cos(a)
y = -1+np.sin(a)
plt = pg.plot(x, y, pen='r')
plt.setAspectLocked()
plt.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```